# the blog owner multisite

Tags: multisite, users

In a multisite, how can I get the ID of the owner of the current blog?

I know how to get the current blogs Id using get_current_blog_id(), so given that ID, how would I fetch the ID of the owner of that blog? (there's just one owner per blog.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this solution for a direct query, but I'd still like to know if there's a template tag I've missed.

```
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

$querystring = "SELECT `user_id`
                FROM `wp_usermeta`
                WHERE (meta_key LIKE 'primary_blog' AND meta_value LIKE $blog_id) 
                LIMIT 1";

$blogownerid = $wpdb->get_var($querystring);
```

Comment: You can use [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) and pass the blog id and "administrator" role, but that makes a slower query

Comment: To better support WP multisite and prevent SQL injection attacks, I'd actually recommend something like `$wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT \`user_id\` FROM \`$wpdb->usermeta\` WHERE \`meta_key\` = 'primary_blog' AND \`meta_value\` = %d LIMIT 1", array($blog_id)))`

Answer (score 3):

I use this workaround to get the ID of the owner of the current blog:

```
$thisblog = $current_blog->blog_id;
$mail = get_blog_option($thisblog, 'admin_email');
$user_from_email = get_user_by('email', $mail);
$user_id = $user_from_email->ID;
```